# @ViewScoped @ManagedBean destroyed when using <h:link includeViewParams="true">

Tags: jsf, destroy, view-scope, viewparams

I'm using Mojarra 2.2.12. I have a case where a `@ViewScoped` `@ManagedBean` is immediately destroyed on page load, although the view is not ended. The problem is reproducible with solely the below in `<h:body>`:

```
<h:outputText value="#{testBean.value}" />
<h:link outcome="other" includeViewParams="true">link</h:link>
```

The `other` must refer to a different view and not the same view. There's no `<f:viewParam>` necessary to reproduce the problem.

And the below bean:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("@PostConstruct on " + this);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void clear() {
        System.out.println("@PreDestroy on " + this);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return "test";
    }

}
```

If we remove `includeViewParams="true"` attribute, then the bean is not immediately destroyed.Why does `includeViewParams="true"` cause this behavior?

Comment: Do you mean to say that it's destroyed on page load or only when the link is clicked?

Comment: The bean is destroyed on page load.

Comment: Can't reproduce it based on information provided so far.

Comment: Then information in the question is lacking. Imagine us having a completely blank project with everything set to bare minimum and defaults, how could we reproduce your problem? The question has to cover all of that.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me, I reproduced it systematically. I work with a showcase project very simple. The project logs PostConstruct on org.exemple.PF.showcase.TestBean
sept. 25, 2015 9:11:13 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeManager <init>
INFO: CDI @ViewScoped bean functionality unavailable
PreDestroy on org.exemple.PF.showcase.TestBean

Comment: The question, not the comments. Comments are volatile. There's an "edit" link below the question.

Comment: Reproduced. Happens only when the link outcome points to different view and you manage bean by legacy JSF `@ManagedBean` instead of CDI `@Named`. And, it's not specific to PrimeFaces. Happens already on `<h:link>`.

Comment: @Balusc, i cannot use CDI because the project is based on Spring and CDI/spring integration is not trivial. Is it a bug or a normal functionnality?

Comment: Spring and Java EE are indeed competitors. As to the problem, this is definitely a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your support, you have definitively a very good understand of jsf technologie. How can i report this bug?

Comment: You can create it here https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES If time allows me I can also take a closer look at it.

Comment: Issue created with id JAVASERVERFACES-4069

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency to pom.xml, I was passed it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please read the comments: _"@B...c, i cannot use CDI because the project is based on Spring and CDI/spring integration is not trivial. Is it a bug or a normal functionnality?"_